# Substracting value from a field in a database table taken from a textbox

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, prepared-statement, actionlistener

I am new in java, in a java project, i want to subtract a textbox value named Quantity(q_field) from 'Available' field of database table Item_detail whenever 'sell' button is clicked and automatically update the table. I wrote some piece of code but its not working. My code is:

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

if(!p_field.getText().isEmpty() && !b_field.getText().isEmpty() && !m_field.getText().isEmpty() && !sell_field.getText().isEmpty() && !c_field.getText().isEmpty()){
int a=Integer.parseInt(q_field.getText().trim());

String sql1="update Item_detail set Available=Available-'a'    where P_name=? and Manuf_name =? and Model_no=?";
String sql2="insert into Sell (`S_id`,`P_name`,`Manuf_name`,`Model_no`,`Date`,`Quantity`,`S.p`,`Cost_price`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
try{
    pst=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql1);

    pst.setString(1, p_field.getText());
    pst.setString(2, b_field.getText());
    pst.setString(3, m_field.getText());
    pst.setString(4, q_field.getText());
    pst.executeUpdate();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product sold  successfully");
    update_table();

    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
```

What will be the correct sql code of 'sql1', i can not understand. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sql1` shall be:

```
String sql1="update Item_detail
                   set Available=Available-?
             where
                   P_name=? 
               and Manuf_name =?
               and Model_no=?";
```

And set values to `pst` query to include value of variable `a` as follows:

```
pst=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql1);

pst.setInt(1, a);
pst.setString(2, ...
...  
pst.executeUpdate();
```

But make sure that you have values set only for that number of palce holders in the query. Otherwise there would be a place holder count mismatch and an SQLException would be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

```
update Item_detail set Available=Available - ? where ...
```

The value of `a` is a parameter of your query, just like the other ones. BTW, you're binding 4 different parameters to the statement, and your query only has 3 parameters (`?` placeholders)

Answer (score 1):

Change your Update Query to this

```
String sql1="update Item_detail set Available=Available-?    where P_name=? and Manuf_name =? and Model_no=?";

 ps.setInt(1,a);
```